# functions like config optional parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i working on ChartPie in D3.js.  I have been trying creat reusable chart. Chart takes data from AJAX call, and then render self. But i want add some optional method (callback) after data Loaded. This method i want set in confing object.

So simple example here:

```
config = {
      url: '/data/data.json',
      callback: {
          'callback1' : function(data){console.log(data);},
          'callback2' : function(data){alert(data);}
      }
}

class Chart {
    construct(container,config){
        this.container = container
        this.config = config

        this.init();
    }
    init(){
        this.fetchData(this.config.url);
    }

        fetchData(url){
        /** some AJAX call on success i want call these optional
         methods from config object. Is it possible and is it good solutions? */ 

          // here needs add some loop which call all callbacks
     }
}
```

Comment: Well yes, it is possible.

Comment: So how can i do this?  is there a pattern for that?

Comment: Make the Ajax call then if it succeeds call the functions in `config.callback`.